# Getting string from array thats inside of an array

Tags: php, arrays

php isn't really my thing but I would need to get the votes and percentage from votes array.

```
stdClass Object
( 
[id] => 312
[type] => item-e
[votes] => Array
        (
            [plus] => Array
                (
                    [points] => Array
                        (
                            [votes] => 1
                            [percentage] => 100
                        )

                )

        )
)
```

I tried this:

```
$items->votes->plus->points->votes
```

But I get "Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string" -error message.

No need to loop it or something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change some object attribute access notation to array access notation:

```
$items->votes['plus']['points']['votes']
```

Comment: Well yes of course. My brain must have been frozen before. Thx alot!

Answer (score 1):

You will have to access the array elements by key, something like this:

```
 $items->votes['plus']['points']['votes'];
```